# TortoiseSVN - Show externals changes

Tags: tortoise-svn

Asked on the Tortoise Forums but haven't received a reply :/

I've been using Tortoise SVN 1.6 for some time now and decided to upgrade. However, I've noticed after the upgrade, that while trying to commit changes the externals do not show up at all.

In version 1.6 if I've made a change in external file, I was not able to commit it, however I was able to review what changes I've done and, if they were sensible, commit them to external repository (by that I mean - copy given file / changes to the appropriate file in external repo, then commit given repo).

To recap:

```
A - repo
-a.file
-B:external folder
--b.file - made changes
-C:external folder
--c.file - made changes
```

Trying to commit A doesn't display changes made in b.file, nor c.file, though these folders come up as changed in explorer. I can also commit them by right clicking each of these folders and then reviewing changes.
It wouldn't be so bad if I had one external, however working with 10> and right clicking on each of them becomes a nuisance.

Is there an option I can enable for the commit to behave as in version 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your shared folders *(B & C)* are missing as part of *repo A*. The directory listing of A should be as followed.

*Contents of A*
`a.file -> file`
`B -> link to external folder`
`C -> link to external folder`

You might have created external links for B as followed, 
`A/B/b.file which links to <B_repo_path>/b.file`
`A/B/bdir1 which links to <B_repo_path>/bdir1`
`A/B/bdir2 which links to <B_repo_path>/bdir2`

What is missing here is the link to directory B itself. So, there should have been a link to

```
/A/B link to <B_repo_path>
```

But sometimes, this is not a desired behavior as the above link fetches everything from *repo B* to */A/B* (But you need only part of *repo B* to be under */A/B*). **You can avoid this by creating a directory (B) as part of repo A**, and creating separate links for each child of B (which you already did above). Remember this directory B is just another directory under *repo A*, which links to nothing on *repo B*.

### Example:

In the following image, there are links to sub-directories of *shared* folder. But there is no actual link to *shared* folder itself.

[image: Links to externals in SuiteShared repo]

This directory is automatically created in your file system, when you try to checkout the main repository for the first time. All you need to do is check in that un-subversioned *shared* directory.

[image]

Comment: Folders B & C are listed within `svn:externals`. When I update repo A, folders B and C are updated and that's exactly the behaviour I'm looking for. What is not happening is that, when I change something in the abovementioned folders, none of the changes made pop up in commit window, while it indeed used to before version 1.6. I have to manually commit each of the folders to its separate repos, which causes the commits to be actually broken down into separate versions, which I don't want

Comment: Right, I had the same issue and fixed it by adding folders B & C (just the folders, not the contents under it) to repo A. When you checkout repo A for the first time, B & C are also checked out, but they are not sub-versioned. Even though the contents of B & C are sub-versioned but the directories themselves are not sub-versioned. You can easily make sure that by looking at the directory properties of B & C.

Comment: I can't add them - when clicking on parent of B, or B itself and selecting `Add` I don't get anything to commit (I also don't get anything when trying to commit the entire repo - as far as I can see the folder is commited, but viewing it through `Repo-browser` it's an external). Just to be sure I've removed all `svn:ignore` and effect is the same.

I've tried to create a B folder within the main repo itself, via `Repo-browser`, and I actually managed to end up with a situation where I have two B folders (I guess it's main:B and ext:B). Updating on such setup gives me a conflict.

Comment: There can't be two folders with the same name in a directory in either Windows or Linux. What is the directory that contains two B folders?

It gives you the conflict for the first time and from the next time onwards, it should be smooth.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - I was just describing what happens in the repo. Let's call it D, but it doesn't matter. No, when updating the repo now I always get an error "Skipped obstructing working copy"